# Кто знает, как в Teamcity получить список проектов, в которых давно не запускались сборки?

Tags: teamcity

Как-нибудь через Rest API можно?

Answer (score 3):

1. Получаете список проектов:

   ```
   /app/rest/projects
   ```
2. Для каждого проекта получаете последний билд (опционально: фильтруете по статусу `status:<SUCCESS/FAILURE/ERROR>` и включаете/не включаете билды в процессе `running:<true/false>`):

   ```
   /app/rest/builds/?locator=project:PROJECT_NAME,count:1
   ```
3. Оставляете только те проекты, в которых дата билда соответствует вашему критерию давности.

За деталями по параметрам запросов отправляю в [документацию](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/REST+API#RESTAPI-BuildRequests).